# Text type alignment

Tags: qml

I have a QML element as follows:

```
    Rectangle {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: rightDrawer.width
        height: 35
        color: "#35FE45"
        Text {
            text: "Settings"
            font.pixelSize: 19
            font.family: "AvantGarde-Medium"
            color: "#ffffff"
            smooth: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
```

Here despite me specifying the vertical alignment as align vertical centre, it still shows the text aligned to the top of the rectangle (see attached figure). I would like to align it to the vertical centre.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add

```
anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter 
anchors.left: parent.left
```

or

```
anchors.fill: parent
```

or

```
anchors.top: parent.top
anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
anchors.left: parent.left
```

to you `Text`.
It aligns it right, but you `Text` item itself is in the top left corner of it's parent.

Comment: @Luca You'r welcome. You should check anchors documentation, it's short but very useful. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html
And it's much better that using layouts.

Comment: I will. Just discovered your code along with anchor.leftMargin does exactly what I needed :) This QML is some powerful stuff!

Comment: @Luca Or I just thought that the best solution would probably be `anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter` + `anchors.left: parent.left`. It does not stretch `Text` with its parent.

Comment: This stretching thing is not a problem for me as my app is running full screen on an embedded device where the screen specs will never change but thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3):

Add These Lines:

```
anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter 
anchors.left: parent.left
anchors.fill: parent
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes